# Error:null value in entry: streamOutputFolder=null

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am unable to run my app in emulator because of this **Error**:

> Error:null value in entry: streamOutputFolder=null

Can someone please help?

Comment: are you using gradle ? @SagarDuhan

Comment: It is difficult for anyone to suggest anything with such less information and no code. Do add what you are trying to do and so verifiable code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use gradle, then you need to delete .gradle directory.

> removing the .gradle directory does indeed fix the problem

**Resource Link:** https://discuss.gradle.org/t/null-value-in-entry-dependencycachedir-null/19191

Comment: Thanks! This is only thing that works after BSOD. InvalidateCache&Restart and/or clean doesn't help

Comment: Thanks. don't know how but it did fix the problem.