# Null Value In Entry: Stream Output Folder Is Null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, null

I am working on Android Application using the Fire base Database. All the data stored perfectly on the Fire base.
The Problem comes when I make some changes and close the Application by Forcing android Studio to be Shut Down.

Now When I open Android to built Project It Gives **Error of Stream output Folder as Null.**
 I have searched on Stack Overflow and find an answer with my Error Resemblance but I didn't understand the Answer completely. 
[Answer Searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649179/errornull-value-in-entry-streamoutputfolder-null)

Here is my App Gradle Code

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.usmanali.medicineinvent"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

The dependancies in App Gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

here is build. Gradle File

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

}
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Do you Invalidate and Restart and then built the project again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is just Resolved by Deleting the .Gradle File in the Project Folder. 
After .gradle File Deletion;
 Built and Clean the Project.